# Adding Tabs using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am trying to make a simple project for adding tabs using fragments.I want to add three fragments in the tabs. But I am getting some errors in code. My fragment getItem method is showing some errors. I don't know how to correct them. My MainActivity code is:

```
    package com.example.tabs;



    public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewpager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(manager));
    FragmentA fragA = new FragmentA();
    FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentC fragC = new FragmentC();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int a) {
        if (a == 0){
            FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        }
        if (a == 1){
            FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
        }
        if (a == 2){
            FragmentC fragment = new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

    }

    }
```

XML file of this is:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: fragment word in getItem are underlined by red. It says change fragment to Fragment, but we want fragment to get returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think it's because you initialized the `fragment` `var` regarding each fragments. As you said: "*fragment word in getItem are underlined by red. **It says change fragment to Fragment***", this happens because the `getItem` method needs to return a `Fragment` Object:

```
public Fragment getItem() { ... }
```

Then, when you declare and initialize the `var`, you set it to each fragments individually and without returning a `Fragment`. Indeed, you return `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` or `FragmentC` when you declare this:

```
FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA(); // same for others
return fragment;
```

It might be better to return a *global* `var` which can equal to `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` or `FragmentC`.

See this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int a) {
    // declare Fragment var
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (a){
        case 0:
            // use and init this var
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            break;
    }
    // return it
    return fragment;
}
```

<sup>BTW, I changed `if/else` condition to a `switch`, there is no difference with `if/else` anyway.</sup>

You can also avoid to use a `var` and return directly the related fragment, as follows:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int a) {
    switch (a){
        case 0:
            // return the related fragment
            return new FragmentA();
            break;
        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
            break;
        case 2:
            return new FragmentC();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two different imports for fragment

> for fragment activity you are importing

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

and for fragment you are using

```
android.app. fragment
```

you can use only one kind of import in class

> use either support.V4 import or android.app.fragment import